# changing svg circles to image

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am new to d3js and I am currently woking on a project which I am stuck on. Here is my syntax

```
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                  .data(data.nodes)
                  .enter()
                //.append("circle")
                //.attr("r",5)
                  .append("img")
                  .attr("class", function(d) { return "flag flag-" + d.code; })




    node.style('left', d => d.x + "px")
            .style('top', d => d.y + "px");

   /*
   node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
       .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
 */
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is change the the circles(I have already commented it out) to image. Can you help me figure out what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append image using following code and adjust 'x' and 'y' coordinates accordingly:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
           .data(data.nodes)
           .enter()
           .append('image')
           .attr('xlink:href', 'http://www.charbase.com/images/glyph/9899')
           .attr('width', '50px')
           .attr('height', '50px')
           .attr("class", function(d) { return "flag flag-" + d.code; });

force.on("tick", function() {
.
.
// node.style('left', d => d.x + "px")
//      .style('top', d => d.y + "px");

node.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x - 25; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y - 25; });
.
.
});
```

I have updated your code in https://jsfiddle.net/o81reo7a/

Comment: with that I am only able to append one single image. My goal is to append as many images as the number of nodes.

Comment: @AvaLucas I have updated my response. You have to include changes in force.on ("tick") function as well as I have mentioned in my response.